# Is there an easy way to find a substring that matches a pattern within a string and extract it?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I know this is open-ended, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Say I have the string `"FDBFBDFLDJVHVBDVBD"` and want to find every sub-string that starts with something like `"BDF"` and ends with either `"EFG"` or `"EDS"`, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: there are neither `"EFG"` nor `"EDS"` in the input i.e., no substring that matches the pattern exists in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "FDBFBDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFGEDS"
>>> print [s[a.start(): a.end()] for a in re.finditer('BDF', s)]
['BDF', 'BDF']
```

Answer (score 1):

> find every sub-string that starts with something like "BDF" and ends with either "EFG" or "EDS"

It is a job for a regular expression. To extract all such substrings as a list:

```
import re

substrings = re.findall(r'BDF.*?E(?:FG|DS)', text)
```

If a substring might contain newlines then pass `flags=re.DOTALL`.

Example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'BDF.*?E(?:FG|DS)', "FDBFBDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFGEDS")
['BDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFG']
```

`.*?` is not greedy and therefore the shortest substrings are selected. Remove `?`, to get the longest match instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as there is no regex expert here yet, I will propose this solution (BTW I added `"BDFEFGEDS"` to the end of your string so it would give some results):

```
import re

s = "FDBFBDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFGEDS"

endings = ['EFG', 'EDS']
matches = []

for ending in endings:
    match = re.findall(r'(?=(BDF.*{0}))'.format(ending), s)
    matches.extend(match)

print matches
```

giving the result:

```
['BDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFG', 'BDFEFG', 'BDFLDJVHVBDVBDBDFEFGEDS', 'BDFEFGEDS']
```